# Junit WebSource type (Registration.class, register) throws ClientHandlerException

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, junit, jersey

I am trying to test my JSON based webservice using Junit client. I get a ClientHandlerException for not having `no-arg default constructor' on my request object and its super class (AMessageStrategy). When I add the`no-arg default constructor`to both of them the server throws a exception`No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement]:`. This has put me in a fix.

Ideally I dont want/need to have a `no-arg default constructor`. The question is, is there a way around it. I just need to serialize a object to json. The object has 2 main fields, a message id and message data. The message data is a pojo.

I have added @XmlRootElement on the request class (no annotations on the fields though).

Please advice, I am kinda stuck. And I am a newbie on Java EE. Let me know if more information is needed on this.

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
com.mcruiseon.common.message.request.RegistrationRequest does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.mcruiseon.common.message.request.RegistrationRequest
com.mcruiseon.common.message.AMessageStrategy does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.mcruiseon.common.message.AMessageStrategy
        at com.mcruiseon.common.message.request.RegistrationRequest

    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:568)
    at test.carpool4all.Registration.testPost(Registration.java:74)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegistrationRequest is not a POJO. Ideally it should be a POJO for it to work.